# Onclick clone/function does not always trigger click handler

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I'm new to the JavaScript world. It seems every time I click add more the very first clone does not  use my click me function but every single clone after the first clone I can use my click me function like the original. What am I doing wrong?

Also please vanilla JS answers only. I want to learn without shortcuts!

More details: when I click the click me button it's suppose to do desired portion / initial portion * amount needed (all in the function convert). When I click add more I want it to add a clone of the element which it does but for some reason the first clone won't let me use the click me feature but every clone after that does.

```js
function gallonToCup(gallon) {
  var gallon = gallon;
  var quart = gallon * 4;
  var cup = quart * 4;
  return "you need to use " + cup + " " + "cups";
}

function quartToCup(quart) {
  var quart = quart;
  var cup = quart * 4;
  return "you need to use " + cup + " " + "cups";
}

function pintToCup(pint) {
  var pint = pint;
  var cup = pint * 2;
  return " you need to use " + cup + " " + "cups"
}

function poundToOz(lb) {
  var lb = Lb;
  var oz = lb * 16;
  return " you need to use " + oz + " " + "ounces"
}

function flozTotbsp(fl) {
  var fl = fL;
  var tbsp = fl * 2;
  return " you need to use " + tbsp + " " + "tbsp"
}

var convertIt = document.getElementById("convertThis").onclick = convert;

function convert() {
  var dp = document.getElementById("dp").value;
  var ip = document.getElementById("ip").value;
  var am = document.getElementById("portionControl").amount.value;
  document.getElementById("converted").innerHTML = (dp / ip) * am;
  var size = document.getElementById("size").value
  if (size == "gallon") {
    document.getElementById("converted").innerHTML = (dp / ip) * am * 16 + " cup";
  }
}
var addMore = document.getElementById("yeah").onclick = clone;

function clone() {

  var fill = document.getElementById("portionControl");
  var clone = portionControl.cloneNode(true);
  clone.id = "";
  var container = document.getElementById("wrapper");
  container.append(clone);
  convert();

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: purple;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
  color: pink;
  border: 5px solid;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0 0 10em 0;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 65%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#converted {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 4px solid pink;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="convert.css">
  <title> Convert Portion</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="title">Brenda Recipe Conversion Site</h1>
  <input id="yeah" type="button" value="Add more" onclick="clone">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <form id="portionControl">


      <input type="text" placeholder="items" value="">
      <input name="amount" type="text" placeholder="amount needed" value="">
      <select id="size">
         <option  value="fluid-ounces" name="hi" >fl oz</option>
         <option value="teaspoon">ts</option>
         <option value="tablespoon">tbsp</option>
         <option value="pint">pt</option>
         <option value="cup">cup</option>
         <option value="quart">quart</option>
         <option value="gallon">gal</option>
         <option value="oz">ounces</option>
         <option value="lb">lb</option>
       </select>
      <input id="ip" type="text" placeholder="intial portions">
      <input id="dp" type="text" placeholder="desired portions">
      <input id="convertThis" type="button" value="click me" onclick=""></input>
      <p id="converted">You need </p>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="convert.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please describe what your code is supposed to do - don’t just drop it here with “you figure it out” ...

Comment: Sorry about that. When I click the click me button it's suppose to do desired portion / initial portion * amount needed(all in the function convert). When I click add more I want it to add a clone of the element which it does but for some reason the first clone won't let me use the click me feature but every clone after that does

Comment: IDs __must__ be unique within the scope of a document - you can not just clone your elements like this and insert multiple elements with the same ID. Uses classes instead of IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a sample demo to explain the approach you must take; Use class instead of id;

`document.getElementsByClassName` will return an array which we will iterate and add event listener.

Every time we clone a button, we will trigger a function `addListeners` will adds event listener to all buttons;

Pure javascript; No jquery

```js
window.onload = addListeners();

function addListeners() {
  let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("clickButton");
  for(i=0;i<buttons.length;i++) {
     buttons[i].onclick = function() {
        alert("button clicked");
     }
  }
}

document.getElementById("clone").onclick = function() {
   let button = document.getElementsByClassName("clickButton")
   let clonedbutton = button[0].cloneNode(true);
   document.getElementById("buttonWrapper").appendChild(clonedbutton);
   addListeners();
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonWrapper">
<button class="clickButton">
click me
</button>
</div>

<button id="clone"> Clone Button </button>
```

Comment: I just change everything to class and it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

With this line of code:

`var convertIt = document.getElementById("convertThis").onclick = convert;`

you are just adding your onclick-event to the first(and initial) "click me"-button.

```
cloneNode()
```

Does not copy your event listeners (from the first and initial button). You have to add the onclick-event to your new clones in your `clone()` method.

Comment: sorry I'm not following

Comment: so your saying just add 
var convertIt = document.getElementById("convertThis").onclick = convert;
inside my clone function?

Comment: after cloning your **portionControl** you have to get the button element of this clone and add your **convert** method as an click event

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems here.

You're trying to fetch values by id, but those id's are not unique per `cloned container`. When searching for an element by id, it paraphrases through the DOM and returns when a value is met with the given criteria.

```js
const elem = document.getElementById('amount');

console.dir(elem.attributes['data-v'].value);
```

```html
<div id="amount" data-v="5"></div>
<div id="amount" data-v="4"></div>
<div id="amount" data-v="6"></div>
<div id="amount" data-v="10"></div>
```

This will always result in `5`, as it is the first element which matches the criteria `element.id==='amount'`. You are cloning the `div#wrapper` element, but the children of this clone preserve their ids.

The other problem is that the cloned `click me` button is not deep cloned, it does not preserve the `onclick` listener

```js
const elem = document.getElementById('clone');

elem.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
const {target} = e;

document.body.appendChild(target.cloneNode(true));
});
```

```html
<button id="clone">clone me</button>
```

The button will clone it self, but when clicking the cloned button you will see nothing happends. This is because the `click` listener is not preserved.

Comment: Honestly I feel more confuse. I will give you the green check because I don't want to waste anyone time. Thank you for your help

Comment: What _exactly_ is still confusing to you? I can try to explain it in a an easier fashion. The biggest problem you have is that you clone an element and its children, but you do not alter their `unique ids` and forget to preserve the attached eventhandler. You're trying to fetch a value by id in the cloned container, but those ids are never changed thus it returns the first element in the DOM. A quick google search brought me to this page which goes more indepth on [how to clone nodes and preserve attached eventhandlers](https://pawelgrzybek.com/cloning-dom-nodes-and-handling-attached-events/).

Comment: This helps alot.Thank you so much!